# POST values are not being returned as expected

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post

I have a form (an invoice) with a set of inputs (for charges).

```
<tr>
    <td><label>Description:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text name="description[]" value="'.$labor->description.'" /></td>
    <td><label>Hours:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text name="hours[]" value="'.$labor->hours.'" size="2" /></td>
    <td><label>Rate:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text name="rate[]" value="'.$labor->rate.'" size="2" /></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="labor_id[]" value="'.$labor->id.'" />
</tr>
```

I am using a javascript function to add another set of these inputs.

```
function moreLabor(table) {

    var table = document.getElementById(table);
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);

    var descriptionLabel = document.createElement("label");
    descriptionLabel.innerHTML="Description:";
    var description = document.createElement("input");
    description.name = "description[]";
    description.type = "text";

    var td1 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var td2 = row.insertCell(-1);
    td1.appendChild(descriptionLabel);
    td2.appendChild(description);

    var hoursLabel = document.createElement("label");
    hoursLabel.innerHTML="Hours:";
    var hours = document.createElement("input");
    hours.name = "hours[]";
    hours.type = "text";
    hours.size = 2;
    hours.value = 1;
    var td1 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var td2 = row.insertCell(-1);
    td1.appendChild(hoursLabel);
    td2.appendChild(hours);

    var rateLabel = document.createElement("label");
    rateLabel.innerHTML="Rate:";
    var rate = document.createElement("input");
    rate.name = "rate[]";
    rate.type = "text";
    rate.size = 2;
    rate.value = 25;

    var td1 = row.insertCell(-1);
    var td2 = row.insertCell(-1);
    td1.appendChild(rateLabel);
    td2.appendChild(rate);

    var remove = document.createElement("input");
    remove.type = "button";
    remove.value = "Remove";
    remove.onclick = function () {
        var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode; //get the row node
        table.deleteRow(parent.rowIndex); //Delete the row index behind it.
    };
    var td1 = row.insertCell(-1).appendChild(remove);

}
```

As you can see, I am using [ ] after repeat input names. The problem is POST is only returning the last set of each values. I looked at the raw Query string and it also only contains the last set of values. Rate, hours, and description are being returned as an array but with only 1 value set each. How to I populate the entire POST array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your syntax, you have combined `type` and `name`

```
 type="text name="hours[]"
```

this should be

```
 type="text" name="hours[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, I feel like an idiot. When I saw my question with colored annotation I noticed th missing "s after type="text

Comment: That's why smart editors and IDE are that much suggested. . . :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
    <td><label>Description:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text name="description[]" value="'.$labor->description.'" /></td>
    <td><label>Hours:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text name="hours[]" value="'.$labor->hours.'" size="2" /></td>
    <td><label>Rate:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text name="rate[]" value="'.$labor->rate.'" size="2" /></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="labor_id[]" value="'.$labor->id.'" />
</tr>


should be

<tr>
    <td><label>Description:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="description[]" value="'.$labor->description.'" /></td>
    <td><label>Hours:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="hours[]" value="'.$labor->hours.'" size="2" /></td>
    <td><label>Rate:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" value="'.$labor->rate.'" size="2" /></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="labor_id[]" value="'.$labor->id.'" />
</tr>
```